# Add permission on \d, \dp commands

Tags: permissions, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL 9.x database and user connect it via psql command. I need a add permission to \d, \dp commands. How to do it?

Answer (score 3):

The `\d` and `\dp` commands simply issue SQL queries in the background. I think the only way to "add permissions" to those psql commands is to change the permissions on the underlying system tables.

To find out which statements are sent, you can start psql with the `-E` option. Then all meta data statements are shown on the console.

Comment: `-e, --echo-queries       echo commands sent to server`
`-E, --echo-hidden        display queries that internal commands generate`

Answer (score 0):

If the user have the privilege of connecting the database and selecting the table , than \d,\dp commond will be permited by using the psql tool